# Rails form keep sending old values after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a form that for some reason always keep same values after error.
For example, if I enter name that already exists, it will get me an error and at the same time it will keep sending old value even if you change it (so you have to refresh page and lose all changes to actually resolve error).

```
   = provide(:title, t(:create_task))
.center
  = form_for :task, url: tasks_path do |f|
    = render 'shared/big_flash'
    = render 'task_error_messages'
    .row.text-center
      .col-lg-10.col-lg-offset-1.col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12
        .jumbotron
          %h2= t(:create_task)
          .row
            .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
              = f.label t(:par_task_name)
              %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_new_name)} info_outline
              = f.text_field 'name', maxlength: 255, class: 'form-control'

              = f.label t(:par_category)
              = f.collection_select 'category', Category.order(:name), :name, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control'}
              = link_to t(:btn_modify_categories), categories_modify_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block', data: { confirm: t(:changes_lost_proceed) }

              = f.label t(:par_task_type)
              = f.select 'task_type', Task::TASK_TYPES_LIST, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'form-control', id: 'type_of_task'}

              = f.label t(:par_score)
              = f.number_field 'score', min: '0', step: '1', class: 'form-control'

            .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
              = f.label t(:par_asset)
              %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_asset)} info_outline
              = f.file_field 'category'

          .description
            = f.label t(:par_description)
            %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_description)} info_outline
            = f.text_area 'name', class: 'form-control'

            = f.check_box 'mathjax'
            = f.label t(:par_mathjax)
            %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_mathjax)} info_outline

          .row
            .correct_solutions.col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
              = f.label t(:par_correct_solutions)
              #generated_correct_solutions
              = button_tag t(:btn_add_correct_solution), type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-toolbar', id: 'add_correct_solution'

            .wrong_solutions.col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
              = f.label t(:par_wrong_solutions)
              #generated_wrong_solutions
              = button_tag t(:btn_add_wrong_solution), type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-toolbar', id: 'add_wrong_solution'

          #close-ended_task{class: 'hidden'}
            = f.check_box 'random', id: 'randomize_task'
            = f.label t(:par_random)
            %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_random)} info_outline
            #randomize{class: 'hidden'}
              .row
                .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
                  = f.label t(:par_number_of_solutions)
                  %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_no_random_solutions)} info_outline
                  = f.number_field 'no_random_solutions', min: '1', step: '1', class: 'form-control'

                .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
                  = f.label t(:par_min_number_of_correct_solutions)
                  %i{class: 'material-icons text-muted', rel: 'tooltip', title: t(:tt_task_min_no_random_correct_solutions)} info_outline
                  = f.number_field 'min_no_random_correct_solutions', min: '0', step: '1', class: 'form-control'

          .btn-group.btn-group-justified.hidden-xs
            .btn-group
              = f.submit t(:btn_create_new_task), class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-toolbar'
            .btn-group
              = link_to t(:btn_cancel), '#', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-toolbar'
          .btn-group-vertical.visible-xs
            = f.submit t(:btn_create_new_task), class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'
            = link_to t(:btn_cancel), '#', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'
```

And my tasks_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.user_id = helpers.current_user.id
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = t(:task_created)
      redirect_to new_task_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Any idea what could be the problem?
I don't want to clean up fields after error, I want to keep them, just on next POST, send new values instead.

Comment: Show your task_params

Comment: You're not using the object `@task`, so are you sure your form will cache old values when it gets re-rendered from `#create`?

Comment: After it gives an error? Yeah sure. After successful creation? Nope. Just as it should be, except that old values are sent even if new ones are specified